# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" Ubuntu v20.10

Tags: server, authentication, pgadmin

I already installed pgadmin4 following https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/ documentation on ubuntu 20.10.

I created a user with an email and a password, then I logged and I got into the pgadmin dashboard, but when I am creating a new server, on the connection tab, It asks me to fill username and password (which I believe are default, postgres and root respectivly) and then i hit save, a dialog error message appears on screen as follows:

```
Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what I missed here?

Thanks

Comment: By Default, the user is 'postgres' and the password is the one which you enter while installing the database. (Version 11,12 I have tested). and enter the password used while installing. Or create a user with login permissions using PgAdmin tool.

Comment: Maybe this helps.

Comment: @David Hey, thanks, I had to create a new db user, I did not use a password when installed postgres the only password i used was to create the pgadmin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, the user is 'postgres' and the password is the one which you enter while installing the database. (Version 11,12 I have tested). and enter the password used while installing. Or create a user with login permissions using PgAdmin tool. Except if you forget to give a password during the install.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables, but here is what I noticed while working with v13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1).

Be cognizant of `/etc/postgresql/<major_version: eg '13'>/main/pg_hba.conf`, especially the trailing portion that describes the method of allowed login depending on context of that login.  If the method is 'peer', the username is the OS login username, and the password is the OS login password.  Essentially, the login process is delegated back to the OS.

Even though you set a password for a given user internal to the database instance, that login pair may not apply to the context of your login.

Docs: [pgsql authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html)

Your context or connection type can change when you specify the host (`-h`) parameter, even if they ultimately go to the same machine.  By default, the connection is attempted as a UNIX socket, but specifying a host turns it into a TCP connection.